# How to select Top 1 1 from table

Tags: linq-to-sql

How can I write this SQL statement in LINQ ?

```
 Select top 1 1 from MyTable
where some condition
```

or something like,

```
Select Top 1 1 from table1 inner join table2 on x=y where condition
```

First()/Take() returns first record. Please let me know if these functions solves the problem and how.

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

```
var result = context.MyTable.Select(x => 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

with `WHERE`:

```
var result = context.MyTable.Where(x => true).Select(x => 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Just add `Select(x => 1).FirstOrDefault()` at the end of the LINQ query.